# I would like to use the opencv to sprinkle the video on the screen

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv to output webcam to the screen.

I output the screen normally.

However, there is one problem.

Noise is generated in the result.

I do not know the reason.

Tell me how to do it

.

The following is the initialization function.

The imshow function was called to test.

```
void CRtspMgr::Init() {
    // init video capture
    if (m_capture == NULL) {
        m_capture = new VideoCapture();
    }

    // set address
    m_capture->open(0);

    namedWindow("video", 1);
}
```

And it is the part that draws the screen.

```
void CRtspMgr::OnPaint()
{
    // draw video mat
    CPaintDC dc(this); 
    if (m_capture != NULL) {
        if (m_capture->isOpened()) {
            RECT r;
            GetClientRect(&r);
            cv::Size winSize(r.right, r.bottom);

            Mat mat;
            m_capture->read(mat);

            // test
            imshow("video", mat);

            int bpp = 8 * mat.elemSize();

            assert((bpp == 8 || bpp == 24 || bpp == 32));

            BITMAPINFO bitInfo;
            bitInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = bpp;
            bitInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = mat.cols;
            bitInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = mat.rows;
            bitInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            bitInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            bitInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            bitInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
            bitInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
            bitInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
            bitInfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
            bitInfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;

            int destx = 0, desty = 0;
            int destw = winSize.width;
            int desth = winSize.height;


            int imgx = 0, imgy = 0;
            int imgWidth = mat.cols;
            int imgHeight = mat.rows;

            StretchDIBits(dc,
                destx, desty, destw, desth,
                imgx, imgy, imgWidth, imgHeight,
                mat.data, &bitInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
        }
    }

    Invalidate();
}
```

[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6R2f.jpg)

Comment: Noise can be due to low light conditions.

Comment: Try setting `bitInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed=1<<bpp` or something large-ish!